# Displaying the first name alphabetically and last name alphabetically after being given a list of names from the user

Tags: pseudocode

design a program that asks the user for a series of names(in no particular order). after the final person's name has been entered, the program should display the name that is alphabetically and the name that is last alphabetically
for example if the user enters the names Kristin, Joel, Adam,zeb, Beth and Chris, the program would display Adam and zeb.
im stuck at the While statment, how can i make the program know what name has alphabetic in order. some people are telling me to use Arrays which i cant, we havent learned it yet. Were using IF and While Statments only.

Comment: In what programming language do you want this?

Comment: its a pseudocode

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so in pseudocode it would look like this:

```
// 1) Get names from user and store them in array
// 2) Order array alphabetically
// 3) Get first element in array and display it
// 4) Get last element in array and display it
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: we havent learned Arrays yet. :( So far we learned IF statments and While

Comment: Well its our class language, based on the professor. cisp 300 which is a pseudocode basically

Comment: @yousif I assume you know how to store values in variables